# Recursive function to calculate if 11 divide a number

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to code a recursive function (used Python) to calculate if 11 divide a number without using rest, subtraction by 11. I just have to use this rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/11_(number)

The code works, but.. I would like to know if there is a way to shrink it, maybe without the need of the variable "k"?

```
def f(n, k=0):
    if n=="" : return 0
    t = ((-1)**(len(n)-1))*int(n[0]) + f(n[1:],k+1)
    if k == 0:
        if t <= -11 or t >= 11:
            return f(str(abs(t)))
        elif t == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return t
```

Comment: I assume this is just for fun or an exercise? Since in reality you'd just use test the value of `int(n) % 11`

Comment: of course.. just an exercise

Comment: @MarzioPinto what datatype are you using as input `n`? is `n` a string? otherwise `len(n)` returns `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

Comment: Yes, a string. I just wrote that in a few minutes. The main concern is about the k variable.. I used a string just for ease

Answer (score 1):

Let's flip the design into a(n unoptimized) tail recursion, so rather than using `k` to detect return to top level, we pass the growing value of `t` downward and do the final calculation when we hit the base case:

```
def f(n, t=0):
    if not n:
        if -11 < t < 11:
            return t == 0

        return f(str(abs(t)))

    return f(n[1:], int(n[0]) - t)
```

Now we're always returning a boolean instead of the previous mixed boolean and integer result!

Answer (score 0):

Is it supposed to be strictly-recursive? Are no iterations allowed? To avoid using k as recursion-depth you could go for a semi-recursive way and calculate t with an iteration and use recursion for the reduction of t.

```
def f(n):
    t = 0
    for i in range(len(n)):
        t += (-1)**(i)*int(n[i])

    if t == 0 :
        return True
    if t < 11 and t > -11:
        return False

    return f(str(abs(t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but you could modify your function to compute the result of `n mod m`, and then check if that is zero. Something like that could be simplified to:

```
def mod11(n):
    if not n: return 0
    diff = int(n[-1]) - mod11(n[:-1])
    if diff < 0: diff = diff and 11 - mod11(str(-diff))
    return diff
```

Usage:

```
>>> mod11("242311") == 0
False
>>> not mod11("242311")
False
>>> not mod11("242308")
True
```

Comment: For many values of `n`, this code throws an exception: "NameError: name 't' is not defined" -- the variable `t` is used but never set.

Comment: @cdlane oops, I worked off of OP's code & naming scheme, but when I posted here I substituted the variable names to be more descriptive. I guess I missed a `t`.

Comment: You still have an undefined `t` variable in the last line `return mod11(str(t))` but I can't convince myself that this line ever gets executed...

Comment: @cdlane yep, you're right again. I didn't spot that one, and my testing after fixing that other `t` didn't raise any exceptions. I've brute forced it to `10000000` without exception, but more convincingly, I think it can be proven that it won't execute.

Comment: For that return to execute, diff must be `>=11`, which means `if diff < 0` failed because that returns values smaller than 11, so `int(n[-1])-mod11(n[:-1])` must be `>=11`. That would mean `mod11(n[:-1])` must be `<=-2`, which is not possible.

Comment: Fixed code to remove that statement, and the unnecessary conditional. Thanks again cdlane

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could do so far for a pure recursion (meaning just one variable). It will return the boolean, True, if the string evaluates to zero mod 11 or a number otherwise.

```py
def f(s):
  if not s:
    return True

  r = f(s[1:])

  # If the rest of the string evaluates to
  # to zero mod 11, there's no need to
  # subtract it from the prefix.
  if isinstance(r, bool):
    return s[0]

  n = int(s[0]) - int(r)

  return True if n in [-11, 11, 0] else n

for x in ['11', '121', '54734', '1099989', '12', '65637', '1565432', '2345651']:
  print (x, f(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule wiki talks about is trying to measure the difference between sum of odd vs. even position digits.

if you rephrase that a bit, it just means as long as 2 sides aren't mangling with each other, you can process them concurrently.

(this existing module of mine is in `awk` but the conceptual approach is the same for all languages) :

```
function mod11(__, _, ___, ____, _____, ______)
{
    sub("^[^0-9+-]*[+-]?[0]*", "", __)
    if ((____ = length(substr(__, ___ *= ___ *= _ = ___ += ___ ^= ___ < ___, _))) < _) {
        return (! ____ ? __ % (--___ - _ * _) : ((substr(__, -_ < +_, ____ = _ * _) % (___ = --___ - _ * _)) (substr(__, ++____))) % (___))
    }
    ___ = ____ = _____ = ______ = ""
    ______ = gsub("...." "...." "...." "..", "&=", __)
    _____ ^= (____ = ! (___ = (_ *= _ += _ ^= _ < _) + (_ = _ * _ - ++_)))
    do {
        ____ = ((____) substr(__, _____, -_____ + (_____ += ___))) % _
    } while (--______)
    return ((____) substr(__, _____)) % _
}
```

Basically what is does is -

1. If the input is small enough, just directly use the built in modulo operator
2. Otherwise, split the decimal digits into chunks of 14-digits at a time
3. It runs from left-end to right-end of the decimal number, since `mod (%) 11` is what i call `base-10 directionally-agnostic`

   -- meaning - horizontally flip the digits, and the `mod 11` stays the same. `"3"` is another example of that
4. Each round, i run it through `% 11` once, and the remainders get pre-pended to significant digit end of next round (so 14-digit chunks is the max I could squeeze out of IEEE 754 without losing a precision).

   —- It's the string-ops equivalent to adding `running-remainder x 10**14` to next round
5. The way the chunks are setup ensures odd and even digits always follow their own track instead of crossing-over. The algorithm (which can take in *any* arbitrarily sized inputs) is linear-time to # of decimal digits (which is pretty decent in binary terms)
6. Then keep repeating until final chunk (plus remainder pre-pend) that's under `2^53 - 1` - before returning the result, inclusive of 1 final modulo operation

The ideas were sourced bits and pieces from existing best practices, and  adapting them to process directly in base-10 without the roundtrip conversion over-head to binary.

(without access to native bit-shifting operators, constantly dividing `ASCII` strings by 2 is rather costly. this is all based on a language without string slices, which may be beneficial in this particular use case)